# What is the remainder when $20^{100!+1} \cdot 100^{20!+1}$ is divided by 541?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My answer is $377$. I would like to know if somebody else interested in got the same answer.

Thanks.

Comment: Explain how you got $377$ in a separate answer if it is different from @RobertZ's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the result is $377$. Note that $541$ is prime and $540=2^2\cdot 3^3\cdot 5$ divides both $100!$ and $20!$. Therefore, by
[Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem),
$$20^{100!+1} \cdot 100^{20!+1}\equiv 20\cdot 100\equiv 377\pmod{541}.$$

Comment: OK. It was I thought.